# How do I let someone access a drive in other computer in a domain?

Tags: share

As a network administrator I want to let someone access c: drive of other computer in the domain. 
How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've taken the security considerations into account, you'd pretty much share it the same way you'd share any other folder:  right-click, properties, advanced sharing.  Choose the AD user you want to be able to access the drive and whether they should have read or read/write privileges.

That seems like an overly broad share, however.  Is it really necessary to share the Windows directory, for example?  Unless you have an unusual use case, I'd strongly recommend only sharing particular directories.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your domain is in Windows,
1. Create user in AD.
2. On the required computer, right click C drive, sharing : add user, permissions - grant all to that user.
3. If that machine is having Windows XP, ensure to restart it.